Is it "safe" to hide a clue within a post's edit history?
I always like to think up puzzles where clues are hidden in unexpected places, like the edit history of a post. My question here is simple: Can it be considered "safe" to hide puzzle clues in the edit history of the question?
By safe, I mean that the clue remains fully accessible for users and guests of all reputation levels, and will continue as such as long as PSE is maintained and operational. An example of an unsafe clue is one that uses external or third-party resources (such as PasteBin, Google Drive, YouTube, etc.), which could potentially become inaccessible over time, ruining the puzzle.
Specifically:

Are users of all reputation levels able to view edit history?
Are site visitors who are not logged in also able to access a post's edit history?
Are there any other potential issues with hiding clues in places like these (such as edit history eventually being deleted after a certain number of years by Stack Exchange)?


Yes, it is more or less safe.
All users, even those not logged in, can view the revision history. Fun Fact: Even if the post has not been edited yet, you can view it under https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/{id}/revisions, which might be useful to see if the question became a HNQ at some point.
Potential Issues:

The diff highlighting works in unexpected ways sometimes, see e.g. edit #32 of this history. I'm fairly sure Jafe just inserted his new entry (maybe by copying Rewan's entry), but the edit history makes it look like he added something to Rewan's entry, which he did not (see source of #31). I think this has mostly to do with multi-line edits and repetitions (both entries start with "500 rep"), although I'm not entirely sure.

I am not aware of a way to preview the diff highlighting, so it might be best to only make "simple" changes (e.g. inserting single letters within sentences)


You should probably tell people to not edit your post. This simultaneously serves as a hint that the revision history is important and also as a reminder to not ruin your puzzle :) But you can always roll-back, unless the #id of the edit is important
If you make multiple edits (and have >= 10 rep), you have to wait a short amount of time (around 5 minutes) until the next one, otherwise the history will show it as a single edit. @bobble notes in the comment that this applies to the initial version of a question as well. So, if you want to have an edit history preserved, you have to wait 5 minutes after posting to edit.
For some people's taste this trick might be too meta, although I think with an appropriate hint it shouldn't be too much of a problem.
We can't know if SE will make substantial changes to how the revision history works or who can view it, but it's been here for a long time and the concept of it (ie viewing what changed) is unlikely to just disappear.


Low reputation users don't have a grace period though.
